# How to create a container with tilt and curve in flutter?

Tags: flutter, figma

I have this figma design as shown in below image, i don't know how to achieve that curve container design in flutter.

[image: [here is the image that i want to achieve in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkP5j.jpg)]

I was exploring the dribble and saw this and just curious how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate any element using the Transform Widget, and the Matrix4 function, which enables you to apply math transforms in any element.

Here is a full example with code:

```
Transform(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.01)
        ..scale(0.5)
        ..rotateY(-0.15)
        ..rotateX(0.15),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: const LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 178, 19),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 221, 221)
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
          border: Border.all(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

There are some libraries that also help you create these kinds of effects, and add interactivity to them, like the [Flutter animate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ClipPathClass(),
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 400,
      height: 450,
      child: Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}

class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    var firstPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstPoint.dx, firstPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width - (size.width / 2), size.height);
    var secondPoint = Offset(size.width - 75, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

I tried to capture this shape by creating ClipPath. You can put and edit the image you want in the Container in ClipPath. I hope it helped. Enjoy your work.

Output:

[image]